# Что значит " : " C# {переменная:D}

Tags: c#

```
Console.WriteLine($"{stepCount}. {dateCurr:D} - {newDate:D} {newDate.AddDays(1):D}");
```

`{dateCurr:D}` - что значит это выражение в виде двоеточия?

Comment: [$ — интерполяция строк (справочные материалы по C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)

Comment: Ну, видимо, формат вывода

Comment: Получается он присваивает D в dateCurr ? Далее в коде вот так Console.WriteLine($"дата №1 {now:d} = {totalDateFirst} день"); И опять обращение {now:d} Что это значит ? То что это формат строки я понимаю.

Comment: вы текст по первой ссылке читали?

Comment: Ваша строка, если грубо говорить, заменяет строку по типу `Console.WriteLine(stepCount.ToString() + ". " + dataCurr.ToString("D") + newDate.ToString("D") + " " + newDate.AddDays(1).ToString("D"));`. Это один из способов вывода текста, весьма удобный способ как я думаю вы уже заметили. `олучается он присваивает D в dateCurr?` - тут нету присвоения, есть лишь вывод с нужным выводом.

Comment: tym32167, да конечно, еще до того как написал этот вопрос тут, но все же полноценно суть не понял, сейчас еще разбираюсь.

Comment: Следующий знак ("D") должен интерпретироваться как указатель на десятичный числовой формат {dateCurr:D} d указывает на десятичный формат?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Выражение `{dateCurr:D}` означает форматирование значения переменной `dateCurr`, используя полный формат даты. Здесь `D` — это один из [описателей стандартных форматов даты и времени](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings). Например:

```
// Текущее время UTC
var dt = DateTime.UtcNow;

// Формат по умолчанию (G): 02.02.2021 04:40:45
Console.WriteLine(dt);

// Короткий формат даты: 02.02.2021
Console.WriteLine($"{dt:d}");

// Полный формат даты: вторник, 2 февраля 2021 г.
Console.WriteLine($"{dt:D}");

// Полный формат времени: 04:40:45
Console.WriteLine($"{dt:T}");
```

Comment: Благодарю Antosha за Ваш ответ!